# Give format to json string

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, format

I have this PHP code, which retrieves and saves a field from a database

```
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('payment');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT level FROM levelPrice WHERE code = 101");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode(array("#" => $rows));
?>
```

And in my HTML I have this:

```
   <script>
    $.getJSON('getLevel.php', function(data) { 
    $("#level").val(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  </script>
```

The thing is, it does return the value, but it appears with a lot of trash. It looks like this in the website: `{"#":[{"level":"4"}]}` 
when I only need the number (e.g. #4) to appear in the website, without all the brackets and stuff. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try something like:" `$("#level").val(data.level[0]);` Remember JSON stands for JavaScript **Object** Notation.  Check the examples toward the end [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  Use `console.log()` to figure out what you are accessing if you get stuck.

Comment: change `JSON.stringify(data)` to `data['#'][0]['level']`?

Comment: Think @Dave got what I was trying to say expressed correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to fetch one row from the database.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT level FROM levelPrice WHERE code = 101");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo json_encode(array("#" => $row['level']));
```

The code then just creates a simple array and JSON encodes it, outputting this:

```
{'#': 'LEVEL-HERE'}
```

Comment: it still appears {"#":"4"}, is there any wey to get rid of the { # " :

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function to get json from javascript and you are echoing out json in your php script. So the result would be json.

You could just use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in your case:

```
$("#level").load('getLevel.php');
```

and change your `echo` statement to:

```
echo '#' . $rows[0];
```

You don't really need to generate an array either, but that is up to you to change if you want to.

Comment: It should work with this..

$query = mysql_query("SELECT level FROM priceLevel WHERE clavePrecioNivel = 101");
$row = array();
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo '#'. $row[0];

But it doesn't load anything in the website with the 
$("#level").load('getLevel.php');